# Bootstrap 3 Grid Layout Issue on Tablet

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, responsive-design

I have problem with the Bootstrap grid system on my new website /services-page ([kenpils.se](http://kenpils.se/services.html).

I would prefer 3 rows with 2 columns instead to make the text in the columns better readable on tablet. Right now the columns are to narrow due to the icon on the left side of each column.

As far as I understand, each row is one div which makes it difficult to slide up the "commercial-column" next to the "editorial-column". There is also a divide30-class between the two rows.

Would appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this I have found works best is to duplicate your content in a tablet layout. then use `visible-*` ([documented here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)) class attributes to hide and make visible specific content to specific screen resolutions. You will need to add `visible-*` class attributes to your `<div class="row">` and change your `col-sm-4` to `col-md-4` see below:

```
<div class="row visible-lg visible-md">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <!-- Your Content 1-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <!-- Your Content 2-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <!-- Your Content 3-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row visible-lg visible-md">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <!-- Your Content 4-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <!-- Your Content 5-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <!-- Your Content 6-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add a section under that in your code duplicating the information and hiding it on larger screen resolutions. see below:

```
<div class="row visible-sm visible-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!-- Your Content 1-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!-- Your Content 2-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row visible-sm visible-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!-- Your Content 3-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!-- Your Content 4-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row visible-sm visible-xs">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!-- Your Content 5-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <!-- Your Content 6-->
    </div>
</div>
```

This will provide the formatting you desire. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your welcome! It stumped me for a few days when I was doing a site. Then when I figured it out I thought "how simple".

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:**  THE BELOW SOLUTION DOESNT ALTER THE LAYOUT AT ALL as you require. It provides an alternative solution !

```
<div class="col-services">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This means that the break wont occur until the width reduces below tablet-zone !

col-sm-4 -> break after tablet-zone width
col-md-4 -> break after normal desktop width

Replace it with

```
<div class="col-services">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4></div>
      <div class="col-md-4></div>
      <div class="col-md-4></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This makes sure that the break occurs at the tablet level itself!